# java.lang.RuntimeException: at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel

Tags: android

On my Google Play App console, I had this crash on a Samsung Galaxy A5 (Android 7):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel (Native Method)
  at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel (InputChannel.java:148)
  at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:39)
  at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:37)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init> (InputBindResult.java:68)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:112)
  at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:111)
  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus (IInputMethodManager.java:840)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner (InputMethodManager.java:1777)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus (InputMethodManager.java:2010)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.displayCompletions (InputMethodManager.java:1022)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown (AutoCompleteTextView.java:1177)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.doAfterTextChanged (AutoCompleteTextView.java:926)
  at android.widget.SearchView.forceSuggestionQuery (SearchView.java:1931)
  at android.widget.SearchView.onTextFocusChanged (SearchView.java:1470)
  at android.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete.onFocusChanged (SearchView.java:2162)
  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal (View.java:6589)
  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch (View.java:9778)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:9757)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:9724)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:9703)
  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent (View.java:12349)
  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent (TextView.java:10097)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:10779)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2549)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:605)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1895)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:3241)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:567)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:11008)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4684)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4741)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6985)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

It's related to SearchAutoComplete but I can't understand how, why? Could you help me to understand this crash guys please?

Thank you very much